# How do I send messages to my view controller instance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to be able to send a message from my mkmapview delegate class to one of my view controllers. I normally send messages by allocating/initing a new instance of that class, but this time I'm trying to send a message to an instance that's already there.

What are the various ways I can do this? Is there a preferred way?

**Edit:**

I found my solution. Not sure if it's the best way, but it's certainly the easiest as far as I can see and perfect for what I need.

What I did was have a static myViewController variable inside my viewController, then have it be set to self in my viewDidLoad. Last, I added a static method to get the static variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I don't understand what you are asking, or it is quite simple. You should have a reference to the instance (say it is called `myInstance`), and then you can simply send a message like:

```
[myInstance myMessage: param1 bla: param2];
```

Of course you should only send messages the receiver (myInstance) can understand. Which they are, depends on the class of the receiver, and on any categories that are defined for its class and in scope.

Comment: I don't have a reference to the viewController instance. The views were created via xib file.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Can't you tell the viewController to send a reference to itself to the class that must know it in awakeFromNib?

Comment: I'm new at this s I'm kind of blanking on how I do this. I imagine I send "self" somehow to the class (the class is RESTdelegate.h btw).

Comment: Give the class that must know the address of the viewController a property for it and then set that property in your awakeFromNib for the viewController.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use NSNotification and NSNotificationCenter to pass messages. Just see the iPhone SDK documentation and you will get how to do that.

Comment: I thought notifications were meant more for sending messages to multiple classes. I just want a quick way to send a message to a single class. Would you still recommend NSNotification as the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, because there is provision that only registered classes will get the messages. So I'll recommend that only.